# Soul Identifying

Tags: magic, reincarnation, identity

In my story, I have a system in place that needs a person to be identified as who they will be by their soul. Reincarnation allows the same souls to be identified time and time again over a period of many years.

**How would I be able to have multiple people have a similar item all around a kingdom that allows them to view a soul to document who that person shall be?**

Would an item/relic be better then, say, a blood smear for identifying a soul signature? The soul must be documented when they are an infant, so no horrible 'rituals' or anything too drastic, as it would be for a week-old baby at the oldest.

**INFORMATION**

- This is a signature of the soul that can be either recognized through sight or some magical marker.
- This signature is matched to a tome that has the same signature with a name attached.
- This would be considered in a time period of the 1300's so no modern medicine or technology.
- You can imagine seeing a code of 1010101 and taking that 'code' or signature to a 'code breaker' so to speak.
- There would be no more then, say, 150 people being born a week so I would need this process of identifying the 'code' of a baby's soul to be time effective and travel effective.
- This process is more magical then scientific but a mixture of the two is acceptable.

Comment: If you're looking for an engineering-esque answer, one that is magical but looks plausible so to speak, then we need more information on what you define as a soul. If it's a unique energy signature for example, you could possibly use an MRI. If it's some other ethereal guide, you may need a more invasive procedure. If it's part of the DNA makeup, you could get away with a standard 'prick test'. Ultimately, more information is needed to give you a good answer.

Comment: A quick question, Do you want an individual soul to be identified as a unique one (like this kid had the soul of the one who died yesterday and lived next door to me), or you want to get a categorization of soul type (like this kid has a type-3 soul and better suited as a soldier while this kid is a type-7 and will be a good trader.)

Comment: Is this a question about How to distribute a Tool/Method Or what that tool/method should be? The first one might be a valid worldbuilding quesiton, but if its the second, it would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: In addition to how many babies are born a week, it would also be helpful to list the approximate population size, as that could affect how "long" or detailed the indicator would have to be.

Comment: Attention, some blood drops are not sufficient enough to represent the soul, Full Metal Alchemist insisted on this point :)

Answer (score 8):

It is said that the eyes are the windows to the soul. You could use this more literally: Reading minute marks on the irises that carry over through each reincarnation.

Answer (score 2):

**View auras.**

[image: aura]
[source](https://xenoversemods.com/mods/xenoverse-2-aura-expansion-pride-troopers-official-release/)

People will get it if you write about someone being able to see auras.  I think they are generally understood to be energy emanations which a person can see under the correct circumstances - inborn gifts, ritual, technology etc.

The aura would be recognized as the entity.  It would look like itself.  You can recognize one the way you recognize anything else - patterns, shapes, movements, relationships, colors.  Describing the aura in a way interesting to your readers is a challenge.  Perhaps a haiku?

Comment: Purply-green in hue: the aura of a madman. Best seen from afar.

Answer (score 2):

Let's think about it on a magical/Yoga/whatever level,

First of all **7 Chakras of the body**.

Do you know as per Yoga there are 7 Chakras in your body that represents various aspects of you like your spirituality, health, mental condition, and many others.

These Chakras needs to be invoked (or awakened) through rigorous practice and also they are awakened from bottom to top one by one.
[image]

For our sake lets skip the rigorous practice, awaken procedure and assume that:

1. For any soul, its Chakras status remains constant.
2. Any Chakra can have 9 different states and will be represented by 9 colors (rainbow, black and white).
3. The awakened state of any Chakra could be VIBGYOR, or black or white.
4. White represents that it is fully awakened, black means it's not awakened and other 7 are in mid status.
5. This gives you 9 possibilities in 7 Chakras giving identification of 4,782,969 individual souls.
6. If you assume that souls have constant gender, then males, females, and transgender give you 3 times the identification.
7. If you have the more/less population you can increase/decrease the colors.
8. Also, make sure that no two souls can have same Chakra states.

**Now, how to identify the states of Chakras,**

Assume, there is a magical stone that can show you the color of any Chakra.

And if you want to get more visual effects, try using the Doctor Strange movie, when that lady hits him and he gets a few projections of him coming out of him.
[image]

> Simply hold the stone in your hand and tap it on a kid's chest, say a
>   magical secret word, this will generate 7 projections behind the kid,
>   each having a color, look at these colors to identify the soul.

**Summary,**

> Use 9 colors of 7 Chakras in 3 separate genders to uniquely identify a
>   soul.

Answer (score 2):

## Spontaneous physical barcoding - that is, birthmarks.

Make everybody have a combination of birthmarks. For instance, ten different places in the body, every place can have a birthmark of different shape and color (light, dark, red). You can even transcribe them in the book as an actual string of numbers or letters.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest the answers so far are no so distinct.

We have [birthmarks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/149834/16729). We could argue that [eye marks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/149801/16729) are a special case.

These has the problem of distinguishing when a mark is a soul identifier (unless we were saying that the iris is identical). A simple solution is to require an special aparatus for the identification. Then we could have marks that are not visible for the naked eye.

That is what you get from [aura marks](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/149798/16729) and [colored chakra](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/149815/16729). *That last one has the issue that awakining chakras would change the code, yet for the purposes of this question we can ignore that.*

So, for abstract, you would use a magic item that would allow you to see some symbols on the person that are invisible to the naked eye, and these symbols serve as soul identification. We could be talking about a language that takes into account the relative position of the symbols, or even their color.

*We do not have to care if they are charka or aura, or whatever. They could be spread across the body, or concentrated on the eyes, it does not matter.*

Answer (score 0):

Others have looked at what to look for, but glosses over the bolded question of how such an item can be distributed.  It requires two things really:

- The ability to identify a soul
- To be able to be replicated and possibly distributed.

If you have a system that requires a soul to be identified, then it follows that a spell, ritual, or something will be devised to facilitate this.  My guess is that one of two situations will develop from this:

1. The creation of these items are limited to a handful in the castle and hand delivered to the surrounding areas in the kingdom
2. The ability to create these items will be part of the training for a local lord, clergy, or similar person of limited authority so that they may carry out this duty semi-autonomously.

### The Marbles

Based on the limited description provided of the magics available, I see the marbles as a simple generic option.  They'd be made in a central place by a skilled glassblower with quality tools and materials.  The spells are either applied there (maybe tying it to a master book of souls), or applied at the destination.  They will be activated while in contact with a newborn and will manifest the soul identifier in the marble itself.  Either contact or a command word can activate the identifying marble.

If you want something reusable, then somebody can copy what is shown in them into the local birth records.  If you don't need it to be reusable, then the marble can be stored with the birth record, or sent to the main castle as proof of birth and the reincarnation found.

As for why it needs to be done in the first week?  For the first week, the baby's soul is at its most clear as there is little to no life to mask the soul's signature and it's burning off the reside of its mother's power for a lack of a better way to put it.

What exactly it identifies is up to you -- be it a special soul energy, chakras, or what have you.

While visuals might be able to identify some reincarnations or truly unique souls, it is not foolproof or 100% accurate which is why this ritual exists in the first place.

Regardless, given the medieval period, I would expect there to be extras in proportion to how important this duty is to the kingdom.